# Como obter o namespace onde a função é chamada?

Tags: php, namespace

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

```
<?php

namespace Bar {
    class test {
        public function test($action) {
            call_user_func($action); // must call \Foo\Action
        }
    }
}

namespace Foo {
    $test = new \Bar\Test;

    function action () {
        echo 'it works!';
    }

    $test->test('action');
}
```

Para uma descrição mais detalhada: Se eu tiver uma função que chame funções definidas pelo usuário com o uso de `call_user_func`, e usar essa função em um namespace `Foo`, para chamar uma função do `namespace Foo`, como eu posso saber que esta função está passada sobre o `namespace Foo`?

Comment: Eu traduzi, será que isso é errado! Achei a pergunta interessante

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não é errado não, fique a vontade para traduzir

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pegar o valor de $action, "explodir" ele com $array = explode("\", $action) e retirar o último valor do array gerado com array_pop() e depois unir o restante com implode("\", $array)